# Count different numbers in list python

Tags: python, list, loops

Hey guys so this is my first year programming and I started with python. I am understanding the programming fairly well but I need help with this homework question.

I have to use a list as my parameter and then return the number of different values in the list. The example list in the question is `[1, 4, 1, 7, 6, 1, 4, 3]` and therefore the returned value should be 5.

Now I know my method of solving it is probably not concise or elegant but if someone could help me and tell me what to change so it works I would greatly appreciate it.

```
def count(mylist):
    newlist = []
    newlist.append(mylist[0])
    stor = False
    for i in mylist:
        stor = False
        for j in newlist:
            if j == i:
                stor == True
        if not stor:
            newlist.append(i)
    return newlist
```

Comment: Are you asking for advice to improve your code or does your code not work? Your title and question are confusing. Please re-word them, so we can help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, a fixed version of your program

```
def count(mylist):
    newlist = []
    newlist.append(mylist[0])
    stor = False
    for i in mylist:
        stor = False
        for j in newlist:
            if j == i:
                stor = True # stor == True test for equality
        if not stor:
            newlist.append(i)
    return len(newlist) # you do not want the list itself but its length
```

And here some suggestions:

- you do not need to initialize `stor` outside the outer loop. This is done two lines later again.
- consider a `break` in the inner loop - this speeds things up a bit (no unneeded comparison)
- `newlist` can be initialized to an empty list without appending the first item. The algorithm stays valid (the inner loop have zero iterations the first time)

here as code-example:

```
def count(mylist):
    newlist = []
    for i in mylist:
        stor = False
        for j in newlist:
            if j == i:
                stor = True
                break
        if not stor:
            newlist.append(i)
    return len(newlist)
```

And more elegant (and pythonic): use the `in`-syntax ;)

```
def count(mylist):
    newlist = []
    for i in mylist:
        if i not in newlist:
            newlist.append(i)
    return len(newlist)
```

Basically `item in something_iterable` returns true, if `item` can be found in `something_iterable`. Most collection of items is iterable (e.g. lists, sets, strings ... `'a' in 'abc'` returns true )

and the most pythonic way but without for/while-loops:

```
def count(mylist):
    return len(set(mylist))
```

Please look into other answers for an explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for! I had a couple breaks in the code earlier but I obviously did not put them in the right place.

Answer (score 7):

Use a [`set()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead:

```
def count(myList):
    return len(set(myList))
```

A set will only hold *one* copy of each value, so converting your list to a set has the handy side-effect of removing all the duplicates. The length of the resulting set is the answer you are looking for.

Using a set is the most efficient method; alternatively you could use a [dict()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) too:

```
def count(myList):
     return len(dict.fromkeys(myList))
```

which is ever so slightly less efficient because it'll reserve space for the values associated with the keys.

If all you want to use is a list, (least efficient), use the `not in` negative membership test:

```
def count(myList):
    unique = []
    for item in myList:
        if item not in unique:
             unique.append(item)
    return len(unique)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use sets here:

```
In [1]: lis=[1, 4, 1, 7, 6, 1, 4, 3]

In [2]: len(set(lis))
Out[2]: 5
```

help on `set`:

```
set(iterable) -> new set object
Build an unordered collection of unique elements.
```

using a for-loop:

```
In [6]: def count(lis):
   ...:     mylis=[]
   ...:     for elem in lis:
   ...:         if elem not in mylis:  # append the element to
                                       # mylis only if it is not already present
   ...:             mylis.append(x)
   ...:     return len(mylis)        
   ...: 

In [7]: count(lis)
Out[7]: 5
```

Also have a look at [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), it returns a sub-class of `dict`, which contains the number of times an element was repeated:

```
In [10]: from collections import Counter

In [11]: c=Counter(lis)

In [12]: c
Out[12]: Counter({1: 3, 4: 2, 3: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1})

In [13]: len(c)
Out[13]: 5
```

Comment: I haven't learned about sets yet, my instructor told us to do it with a for or while loop and said we should be iterating through the list. Sorry I should have posted that in the question.

Comment: @AlexMann added a for-loop based solution as well.

Comment: `collections.count` might be worth mentioning, especially if OP wants to improve from just the number of unique elements

Answer (score 1):

```
stor == True
```

You're not actually setting `stor` to `True` here.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use `set`, try

```
def count(mylist):
    mylist.sort()
    total = 0
    for k in range(1, len(mylist) -1 ):
        if mylist[k] != mylist[k + 1]:
            total += 1
    return total
```

This sorts the list and then increments the counter each time an element is unequal to the next one.

---

If you can't use sorting, you'd normally keep track of counted values. That is too obvious though, so here is a funny way to do it without keeping a list of values you already counted:

```
def count(mylist):
    total = 0
    for k, value in enumerate(mylist):
        total += 1 / mylist.count(value)
    return total
```

So for `[1, 4, 1, 7, 6, 1, 4, 3]`, the weights are `[1/3, 1/2, 1/3, 1, 1, 1/3, 1/2, 1]` which adds up to `5` as it should.

This is a much more awesome way than what your teacher is looking for (despite the inefficiency of this method).

Comment: awesome thanks. If I was to do it without sorting the list how would it change? My prof said it could be an "exam question" only we would not be allowed to sort the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are supposed to use a loop, then this is the way(or one of them). :)

```
the_list = [1, 4, 1, 7, 6, 1, 4, 3]

def count(the_list):
    unique_list = []
    for item in the_list:
        if item not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(item)
    return len(unique_list)
```

Comment: the `else` part is useless here.